# ISC DHCP server not dynamically updating DNS

Tags: configuration, ldap, isc-dhcp, ddns

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server, running an `isc_dhcp_server` and the `bind9` DNS server.
Bind acts as a cache, *and* it maintains the `.m` domain (and zone) on my local network.
The server's address is `10.0.0.1`, and its FQDN is `server.m`.

**The problem is that the DHCP server is not sending any DDNS updates to the DNS server.** I have tried changing the DHCP server's configuration (using LDAP)in numerous ways, but to no avail. E.g.: I moved all the config statements that are now part of the `subnet` to it's parent `group`. Both configurations seem to work equally (un)well.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I *did* however manage to send a manually constructed DDNS update to the DNS server, like [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/531165/133759) shows how to do. This worked perfectly, and the updates showed up in my system logs. Even if I'm using the wrong key with `nsupdate`, that's being logged. Thus, my bind configuration should be fine.

My DHCP server is configured using LDAP, as per this [tutorial](http://wiki.herzbube.ch/index.php/ISCDHCP). The resulting config file (which is generated from the LDAP tree during the DHCP server's startup sequence) looks like the code posted below. (result of `ldap-debug-file "/var/log/dhcp-ldap.conf";`)

You might wonder "*Where are the `host` entries?*". In my LDAP directory, those are located inside the `group`, as `objectClass: dhcpGroup`, but they don't appear in the derived `dhcp-ldap.conf` file. Those hosts that I configured with a `dhcpHWAddress: ethernet 01:23:45:67:89:ab` property are considered to be `known-clients`, since these end up receiving addressed from the `range 10.0.0.64 10.0.0.127`. All the hosts that I configured that way also have a `dhcpOption: host-name "some-host-name"` and `dhcpStatements: ddns-hostname "some-host-name"`.

Despite the `known-clients` being recognized, I don't see *any* attempts of the DHCP server trying to update any DNS records in my logs.

```
log-facility local7;
default-lease-time 43200;
max-lease-time 86400;
key DHCP_UPDATER { algorithm hmac-md5; secret somesecretkey; }

group {
    option domain-name "m";
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option broadcast-address 10.0.0.255;
    option time-servers server.m;
    option routers server.m;
    option domain-name-servers server.m;

    subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        authoritative;
        update-static-leases on;
        deny client-updates;
        ddns-update-style interim;
        ddns-updates on;
        zone 0.0.10.in-addr.arpa. { primary server.m; key DHCP_UPDATER; }
        zone m. { primary server.m; key DHCP_UPDATER; }
        ddns-rev-domainname "0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.";
        ddns-domainname "m.";
        pool {
            range 10.0.0.128 10.0.0.192;
            allow unknown-clients;
        }
        pool {
            range 10.0.0.64 10.0.0.127;
            allow known-clients;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the dhcpd.conf(5) man page:

```
The ddns-update-style parameter

     ddns-update-style style;

     The  style  parameter  must  be  one of ad-hoc, interim or none.  The
     ddns-update-style statement is only meaningful in the outer  scope  -
     it  is  evaluated once after reading the dhcpd.conf file, rather than
     each time a client is assigned an IP address, so there is no  way  to
     use different DNS update styles for different clients. The default is
     none.
```

In your config, you have put `ddns-update-style` inside a `subnet` block. According to the above, `ddns-update-style` is only meaningful in the outer scope, so your config as written will not work. Move `ddns-update-style` to the outer scope, i.e. outside of any block.